# Writing multiple files asynchronously

Tags: node.js

While trying to understand the event loop, I wrote a quick snippet to test my assumptions. No surprise, they were wrong!

```
import fs from 'fs'

let bufferA = new Buffer(1e+9)
bufferA.fill(0)

let bufferB = new Buffer(1e+0)
bufferB.fill(0)

let fileA = fs.openSync('fileA', 'w')
let fileB = fs.openSync('fileB', 'w')

fs.write(fileA, bufferA, 0, bufferA.length, (err) => { console.log(err || 'wroteA')})
console.log('Started writing to A..')
fs.write(fileB, bufferB, 0, bufferB.length, (err) => { console.log(err || 'wroteB')})
console.log('Started writing to B..')
```

I was hoping that both files would be written to asynchronously (i.e., fileB finishes first), but the output is as follows:

```
Started writing to A..
Started writing to B..
wroteA
wroteB
```

With a delay before `wroteA` is shown. So while `fs.write` seems to operate  asynchronously from my code (i.e., the logs are written first) it seems like you can only have one file writing at a time?

Comment: So, your question leaves this for the reader to figure out for themselves, but are you saying you are surprised that fileB doesn't finish first because the number of bytes to write to it are so much smaller (1GB vs 1 byte)?  Is that what this question is about?

Comment: On my  system, i get `wroteB` displayed long before `wroteA` as I would expect.  What version of node.js and what OS are you running on?  I'm running node v0.12.2 on Windows 10.  I cannot reproduce the result you say you got.

Comment: Why have you gone non-responsive?  I've tested your scenario and received a different result, explained that to you and asked you some questions and now you're not around.

Comment: I got the same result as I described above in node v4.0.0 on Windows 8.

Comment: @jfriend00 1 hours between responses is hardly unresponsive. Stack overflow is asynchronous after all! ;)

It is very interesting that you get wroteB much sooner, as I thought this experiment would show. I am on v4.1.1 on OS X 0.11.1

Comment: If someone engages with your question to ask clarifying questions and you don't respond for an hour, you're a lot less likely to get as much involvement in helping as if you're much more responsive than that.  That's just a fact in how Stack Overflow works.  If you want to maximize your chances of getting help, you will check back multiple times within the first 30 minutes after posting to see if your question was understood properly or if people have questions.  Many questions are closed in the first 30 minutes if not clear and there is no clarification from the OP.

Comment: Since Windows does not exhibit the behavior you show, I guess you'll have to find someone else on OSX who can see if they can verify your behavior.  Disk I/O in node.js is supposed to use a thread pool so that multiple requests can be in process at the same time to provide asynchronous behavior.  That is at least how it works on Linux and Windows.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for testing, I get the same results as you on my Ubuntu machine with node v0.12.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Ben Noordhuis on the GitHub issue you opened for this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3623#issuecomment-152869729):

> Libuv serializes disk writes on OS X due to a nasty quirk documented [here](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.7.5/src/unix/fs.c#L623-L630).  It's possible newer OS X releases fare better but that hasn't been tested.

Node.js uses libuv for things like file I/O. So...it's serialized but (crucially) does not block the event loop. So fileA may block writing to fileB, but not all your other JS stuff. And only on OS X.